# How to make a corner only rectangle with Adobe Fireworks

Tags: shapes, adobe-fireworks

Using the Rectangle tool, how can I make a rectangle with only the corners being visible? Something like this image:

[image]

**Note:** I made this one using two other "white" rectangles to hide the invisible part of the blue rectangle. But this method isn't very clean as you may guess.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right way, you just have to add one more step.[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is kinda similar to what I did, I just used a  blue stroke instead of punching two rectangles to get the blue rectangle. the problem with your method is you can't change the width of the blue rectangle,

Comment: @Asme, You can change the width by dragging individual vector points of the end result manually, or repeating the process for each different size you want. Repeating is a common way to do it, because this is how vector shapes work. If you want to be able to change the width of the lines by typing it in, you can use Knife tool on a single rounded rectangle to cut out sides and then delete them. What will be left are the single vector lines of the corners. You can apply any width to that, but I don't recommend that because you will have less control over the edges, filling and other effects.